# What function is the best for solving differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

dy/dt = -y^2, what is the best function to solve this equation?

Comment: Try using DSolve.

Answer (score 1):

As bbgodfrey mentions you can do the following to solve the equation generally:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == - y[x]^2, y[x], x]
```

Or if you have a boundary condition (in this case I have chosen y=1 at x = 0), you can use DSolve to get the specific solution:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == - y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

Hope that helps!

Best,

Ben